Mask the Blur effect in compositor
This is my render layer ( 1920 x 1080) :

I draw a mask in image editor :

In compositor I add a blur node and try mask the blur effect :

composite result (nothing changed) :

The mask doesn't work in the blur , what is wrong ?
This is the result i'm looking for :


You have to turn on Variable Size, for masking to work with the Blur node.

Resources (Blender 3.6.12): 
